# Input dictionary key to have value be checked somewhere else

Tags: python, dictionary, key, multiple-value

I've got another question. You guys have been super helpful.

So I created a dictionary between NFL team names and their codes. The dictionary looks like this:

```
team_code = []
franchise_list = []

for row in NFL_teams:
  franchise = str(row["team_name"])
  team_id = str(row["team_id"])
  team_code.append(team_id)
  franchise_list.append(franchise)
  
nfl_dict = {}
for a,b in zip(team_code,franchise_list):
  nfl_dict.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)
```

This dictionary has multiple team names (values) attached to 3 letter team codes (key). For example:

```
  organization = input("Pick a team: ") <- LAR as input
  print(nfl_dict[organization])         <- ['Los Angeles Rams', 'St. Louis Rams', 'Los Angeles Rams'] as output
```

Later, I need to input a team exactly as it shows in the dataset in order to get back its record. A portion of that code looks like this:

```
season_year = input("Pick a year from 1966 onwards: ")
team = input("Pick a team: ")

for row in NFL_stats:
  if row["schedule_season"] == season_year:
    home = row["team_home"],row["score_home"]
    away = row["team_away"],row["score_away"]

    if team == home[0]:
      my_team = home
      other_team = away
    elif team == away[0]:
      my_team = away
      other_team = home
    else:
      continue
```

However, a team's name is not the same from year to year, as shown above with the LA Rams. And as it stands, if I enter a year where the team was in St. Louis as opposed to Los Angeles (for example 1999), I won't get a record back since the data states "St. Louis Rams".

I want to be able to enter the dictionary key (the three-letter code) instead of the team name. How would I be able to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give workable definitions for `NFL_teams` and `NFL_stats` so it's possible to run your code?  The entire data set isn't needed, but you should include enough for the examples you talk about to be debuggable.

Comment: Sure.

`nfl_stats` is a .csv file with every NFL score ranging back to 1966. For the columns `team_home` and `team_away`, the full name of the team is listed for every individual game. Example: Washington is listed as Washington Redskins in games up until 2019 and Washington Football Team in both 2020 and 2021.

`nfl_teams` is a .txt file that has franchise data in it. It has every version of a team's name as it appears in the .csv file along with a corresponding team code (each version of the Rams has the code LAR beside it).

Comment: I pasted that into my Python interpreter but I got a `SyntaxError`.  Maybe there's something you could add to your question that starts with `NFL_teams = ...` and `NFL_stats = ...` that would make your code run?

Comment: To do so, you would need the original data sets since my code is based on reading those data sets.

Comment: As I said, just provide enough of the dictionaries for the examples you're talking about to work.  I suppose I could eventually reverse-engineer it based on your description, but it's much easier for you to just dump out those dictionaries and then copy and paste the first few pertinent entries.  :)  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `{'ARI': ['Arizona Cardinals', 'Phoenix Cardinals', 'St. Louis Cardinals'], 'ATL': ['Atlanta Falcons'], 'BAL': ['Baltimore Ravens'], 'BUF': ['Buffalo Bills'], 'CAR': ['Carolina Panthers'], 'CHI': ['Chicago Bears'], 'CIN': ['Cincinnati Bengals'], 'CLE': ['Cleveland Browns', 'Cleveland Browns'], 'DAL': ['Dallas Cowboys'], 'DEN': ['Denver Broncos'], 'DET': ['Detroit Lions'], 'GB': ['Green Bay Packers'], 'HOU': ['Houston Texans'], 'IND': ['Baltimore Colts', 'Indianapolis Colts'], ... }`

Comment: Is that `NFL_stats` or `NFL_teams`?  The code depends on both of them.

Comment: I don't see how the dict above is *either* of those, actually, since it doesn't have `'team_name'` or `'scheduled_season'` keys as your code expects.

Comment: So you need to basically have it input `'LAR'`, and have it return the correct team name based on the year? So if it's 1999, give you `'St. Louis Rams'`, but if the year entered is 2021, give you `'Los Angeles Rams'`?

Answer (score 0):

As Samwise commented, there is a lot missing from your post, such that a full understanding is difficult.  But the question you ask seems to just be, how to find something in a Python dictionary from its key.  If that's the case, here is the simple answer, from the Udemy Python course I took:

```
# Make a dictionary with {} and : to signify a key and a value
my_dict = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}

# Call values by their key
my_dict['key2']
```

That code returns 'value2'.

2/25/2022 update:  Based on your comment, there are several ways to avoid the  error you are getting.  I thing you need something like along the following lines. I calculated the number of items with "len" just to show you, but I didn't even need that:

- The "for" command just knows how many items there are.
- If you only want the last item in a list, the [-1] index returns it without you having to know the length.

```
my_list =  ['Los Angeles Rams', 'St. Louis Rams', 'Los Angeles Rams']

size_of_list = len(my_list)
print ( f"my_list has {size_of_list} items, as follows:\n" )
       
for team in my_list:
    print (team)

last_team = my_list[-1]
print ( f"\nLast team on my_list: {last_team}" )
```

The output of that code is:

```
my_list has 3 items, as follows:

Los Angeles Rams
St. Louis Rams
Los Angeles Rams

Last team on my_list: Los Angeles Rams
```

Another approach to error messages, like you are getting, is to use a "try / except" block of code.  But that is probably not as appropriate here.

If you are interested, I just learned all this stuff in a online course by Udemy.  I really liked it: https://www.udemy.com/course/python-from-zero-to-hero/

Eliot

Comment: That's not the issue.

I can read the values attached to any given key. For example, when I call LAR, I get `['Los Angeles Rams', 'St. Louis Rams', 'Los Angeles Rams']` which is what I want the code to do.

However, because some keys have only 1 value attached to them and other keys have multiple values, I want a key to check if the first value exists and then move onto the second one if the first one isn't there. When I try to do so, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.
That's the issue at hand.